# Results of linear vs. multiple regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

since i am writing my thesis right now, i have stumbled across a problem which i hope some of you can help me with regarding regression

first i used the simple regression x1 (satisfaction) -> y (grades) with a sig. coefficient of .40

afterwards i analyzed another predictor with the simple regression x2 (efficient working) -> y with a sig. coefficient of .55

afterwards i combined x1 and x2 using multiple regression, however for that the coefficients were much smaller (still sig.)  x1 .24 and x2 .45

i checked for multicollinearity already (.358), tolerance (.87) and vif (1.14)

how can i explain the results of the multiple regression especially in regard to the simple one i did before?

thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This doesn't look unusual. Why do think there is something wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to explain the results of the multivariable regression in regard to the simple linear regressions? What the goal of these analyses?